# Updating a JS plugin for touchscreens

Tags: jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile, touch-event

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var dragging = false,
    scrolling = false,
    resizing = false;
  //cache jQuery objects
  var imageComparisonContainers = $('.cd-image-container');
  //check if the .cd-image-container is in the viewport 
  //if yes, animate it
  checkPosition(imageComparisonContainers);
  $(window).on('scroll', function() {
    if (!scrolling) {
      scrolling = true;
      (!window.requestAnimationFrame) ?
      setTimeout(function() {
        checkPosition(imageComparisonContainers);
      }, 100): requestAnimationFrame(function() {
        checkPosition(imageComparisonContainers);
      });
    }
  });

  //make the .cd-handle element draggable and modify .cd-resize-img width according to its position
  imageComparisonContainers.each(function() {
    var actual = $(this);
    drags(actual.find('.cd-handle'), actual.find('.cd-resize-img'), actual, actual.find('.cd-image-label[data-type="original"]'), actual.find('.cd-image-label[data-type="modified"]'));
  });

  //upadate images label visibility
  $(window).on('resize', function() {
    if (!resizing) {
      resizing = true;
      (!window.requestAnimationFrame) ?
      setTimeout(function() {
        checkLabel(imageComparisonContainers);
      }, 100): requestAnimationFrame(function() {
        checkLabel(imageComparisonContainers);
      });
    }
  });

  function checkPosition(container) {
    container.each(function() {
      var actualContainer = $(this);
      if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() * 0.5 > actualContainer.offset().top) {
        actualContainer.addClass('is-visible');
      }
    });

    scrolling = false;
  }

  function checkLabel(container) {
    container.each(function() {
      var actual = $(this);
      updateLabel(actual.find('.cd-image-label[data-type="modified"]'), actual.find('.cd-resize-img'), 'left');
      updateLabel(actual.find('.cd-image-label[data-type="original"]'), actual.find('.cd-resize-img'), 'right');
    });

    resizing = false;
  }

  //draggable funtionality - credits to http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/draggable-without-jquery-ui/
  function drags(dragElement, resizeElement, container, labelContainer, labelResizeElement) {
    dragElement.on("mousedown vmousedown", function(e) {
      dragElement.addClass('draggable');
      resizeElement.addClass('resizable');

      var dragWidth = dragElement.outerWidth(),
        xPosition = dragElement.offset().left + dragWidth - e.pageX,
        containerOffset = container.offset().left,
        containerWidth = container.outerWidth(),
        minLeft = containerOffset + 10,
        maxLeft = containerOffset + containerWidth - dragWidth - 10;

      dragElement.parents().on("mousemove vmousemove touchmove", function(e) {
        if (!dragging) {
          dragging = true;
          (!window.requestAnimationFrame) ?
          setTimeout(function() {
            animateDraggedHandle(e, xPosition, dragWidth, minLeft, maxLeft, containerOffset, containerWidth, resizeElement, labelContainer, labelResizeElement);
          }, 100): requestAnimationFrame(function() {
            animateDraggedHandle(e, xPosition, dragWidth, minLeft, maxLeft, containerOffset, containerWidth, resizeElement, labelContainer, labelResizeElement);
          });
        }
      }).on("mouseup vmouseup", function(e) {
        dragElement.removeClass('draggable');
        resizeElement.removeClass('resizable');
      });
      e.preventDefault();
    }).on("mouseup vmouseup", function(e) {
      dragElement.removeClass('draggable');
      resizeElement.removeClass('resizable');
    });
  }

  function animateDraggedHandle(e, xPosition, dragWidth, minLeft, maxLeft, containerOffset, containerWidth, resizeElement, labelContainer, labelResizeElement) {
    var leftValue = e.pageX + xPosition - dragWidth;
    //constrain the draggable element to move inside his container
    if (leftValue < minLeft) {
      leftValue = minLeft;
    } else if (leftValue > maxLeft) {
      leftValue = maxLeft;
    }

    var widthValue = (leftValue + dragWidth / 2 - containerOffset) * 100 / containerWidth + '%';

    $('.draggable').css('left', widthValue).on("mouseup vmouseup", function() {
      $(this).removeClass('draggable');
      resizeElement.removeClass('resizable');
    });

    $('.resizable').css('width', widthValue);

    updateLabel(labelResizeElement, resizeElement, 'left');
    updateLabel(labelContainer, resizeElement, 'right');
    dragging = false;
  }

  function updateLabel(label, resizeElement, position) {
    if (position == 'left') {
      (label.offset().left + label.outerWidth() < resizeElement.offset().left + resizeElement.outerWidth()) ? label.removeClass('is-hidden'): label.addClass('is-hidden');
    } else {
      (label.offset().left > resizeElement.offset().left + resizeElement.outerWidth()) ? label.removeClass('is-hidden'): label.addClass('is-hidden');
    }
  }
});
```

```css
/* SLIDER CSS */

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.cd-image-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0em auto;
}

.cd-image-container img {
  display: block;
}

.cd-image-label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  color: #000000;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-size: 10px;
  margin: 5px 35px 0 35px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .7);
  font-weight: bold;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-family: 'AudiTypeExtendedNormal', Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  opacity: 0;
}

.cd-image-label.is-hidden {
  /*visibility: hidden;*/
  opacity: 0;
}

.is-visible .cd-image-label {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  -moz-transform: translateY(0);
  -ms-transform: translateY(0);
  -o-transform: translateY(0);
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.cd-resize-img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* Force Hardware Acceleration in WebKit */
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  -o-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  border-right: solid 1px #dedede;
}

.cd-resize-img img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  max-width: none;
}

.cd-resize-img .cd-image-label {
  right: auto;
  left: 0;
}

.is-visible .cd-resize-img {
  width: 50%;
  /* bounce in animation of the modified image */
  -webkit-animation: cd-bounce-in 0.7s;
  -moz-animation: cd-bounce-in 0.7s;
  animation: cd-bounce-in 0.7s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes cd-bounce-in {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  60% {
    width: 55%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes cd-bounce-in {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  60% {
    width: 55%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

@keyframes cd-bounce-in {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  60% {
    width: 55%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

.cd-handle {
  position: absolute;
  height: 22px;
  width: 44px;
  /* center the element */
  left: 50%;
  top: 55%;
  margin-left: -22px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  background: #000000 url("https://images.clickfunnels.com/09/a714400d3211e7a0bd7d7140585054/cd-arrows.svg") no-repeat center center;
  cursor: move;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) scale(0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) scale(0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) scale(0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) scale(0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) scale(0);
  z-index: 300;
}

.cd-handle.draggable {
  /* change background color when element is active */
  background-color: #3a3a3a;
}

.is-visible .cd-handle {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) scale(1);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) scale(1);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) scale(1);
  -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) scale(1);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) scale(1);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s 0.7s, opacity 0s 0.7s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.3s 0.7s, opacity 0s 0.7s;
  transition: transform 0.3s 0.7s, opacity 0s 0.7s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<figure class="cd-image-container">
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/751678/marioPhoto-2.jpg" alt="Original Image">
  <span class="cd-image-label" data-type="original"></span>

  <div class="cd-resize-img">
    <!-- the resizable image on top -->
    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/751678/marioPhoto-1.jpg" alt="Modified Image">
    <span class="cd-image-label" data-type="modified"></span>
  </div>

  <span class="cd-handle"></span>
</figure>
```

I'm using a JS plugin for an image comparison slider, and it's built in such a way that it only works on desktop. I understand that touch events are needed to make the experience better on mobile devices, and I'm unsure what needs to be updated in the code for this to happen.

I've attempted making use of `mousemove`, `vmousemove` and `touchmove` without success. Please help!

Comment: I would check https://jquerymobile.com/ - how there are solved touch events.